# Switch on model attribute doesn't work - laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I got a strange problem today.
I have a very complex database with much relationship. 
On my model, i got athe following function:

```
public function resource(){
    dd($this->getAttributes());
    switch($this->content_type){
        case Content::TYPE_TASKLIST:
            return $this->belongsTo('Tasklist', 'content_id');
        case Content::TYPE_FEEDBACK:
            return $this->belongsTo('Feedback', 'content_id');
        case Content::TYPE_SURVEY:
            return $this->belongsTo('Survey', 'content_id');
        case Content::TYPE_MEMO:
            return $this->belongsTo('Memo', 'content_id');
        case Content::TYPE_GEAR:
            return $this->belongsTo('Gear', 'content_id');
    }
    return $this->belongsTo('Resource', 'content_id');
}
```

This function must change the relation and give me the good one to get the right informations.
I checked thousand times the columns name but i can't get working the switch.

The $this->content_type is always null so it doesn't change the relationship.
I tried a lot. As you can see,I dd() the model attribute but it return me just an empty array.

I don't understand why this function doesn't work. All other realtions i get until these différents kind od resources are okay. I got the irght informations about the resources id and content type but simply doesn't work.

Someone got an idea why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your trying to implement a Polymorphic relationship and Laravel has an elegant way to do this.

See http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#polymorphic-relations for details.

Also, make sure you have an instance of the model with loaded data to be able to have the attributes populated. Otherwise, it will just be null as you stated.